# Angular 7 navigate not working in 'if' condition

Tags: angular

Component.ts

```
if(data['status'] === 'success'){
    this.router.navigate(['/admin'])
    //return false
    alert("successfully login");
} 
else {
    alert("invalid login");
}
```

The "successfully login" alert works well , but page navigation fails .Already imported Router and declared as router in constructor.

Comment: It should work basically. may be you can try 'navigateByUrl'

Comment: can you create a create a demo at https://stackblitz.com/ it will be easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

Is the datatype of the `data['status']` string? If not, use `==` instead of `===`

Then check if you imported RouterModule and Routes:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

And then check if the [configuration](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration) is Ok.